# iPhone FTP Integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, ftp

Can someone point me in the direction of an Objective-C (or c/c++) library, or tutorial (Objective-C) that teaches uploading or downloading via FTP? Preferably one that shows how to download a file to a temp dir, then upload it later? I don't mind one aimed at OSX, but my goal is the iPhone / iPad. I'm still googling, but the results are slim at best.

EDIT: This looks like it'll do the trick:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Thanks guys!

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434552/best-ftp-objective-c-wrapper-for-iphone

Comment: Yea, that was the one I looked at, but couldn't get it to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit should do the job

Comment: That is the one I looked at but couldn't get it to compile. It said base-sdk missing, so I changed it to OSX 10.6, and there were 90 some errors.

Comment: It wants 10.4u, but all I have is 10.5 / 10.6, when I set it to 10.6 I get these: http://www.qfpost.com/download.do?get=6c35fdb7ee20ffb8ab4b426df8fcf088

Comment: I'd upload that to my site, but ftp transfer is blocked where I am atm :O

Comment: @josh perhaps try this: http://s7ftprequest.googlecode.com/files/s7ftprequest-basic-release.zip is an earlier version of the s7ftp that apparently works, ive not used it personally but people seem to have had success on the iPhone platform with it.

Comment: Well I turned off warnings as errors (i don't remember turning it on...) but, now it says: No launchable executable present at path: /Users/MacBook/Downloads/karelia-ConnectionKit-v1.2.3-0-g21b2243/karelia-ConnectionKit-21b2243/build/Debug/DropletHelper.app

Comment: Cleaning all targets... But no dice.

Comment: hmmm, its mainly the framework which will be in the products directory that you need, but if you want it for the iPhone then i dont know if we can get this to work.  I did just find this in the apple docs, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html so hopefully this will help?

Comment: Reextracted, moved the dir, renamed, cleaned, build, fail: No launchable executable present at path: /Users/MacBook/Downloads/connectionkit/build/Debug/DropletHelper.app

Comment: Spectacular! I can't test here, but it looks promising! You should edit your original post, so I can accept it :)  Well, I can compile it here, and it works, but port 20 is blocked :\