# Possibilities of FTP download and display content

Tags: ios

I have created in android an application that downloads via FTP connection some content (pdf, mp4, jpg) and saves it on sdCard then the the user can view each content file via some buttons on the app. My client asked me to created the same thing for iPad. My question if it is possible to create FTP connection and download needed content then display it in my app whenever i need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Also this answer on stackoverflow:

[iPhone FTP Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281109/iphone-ftp-integration)

Or maybe:

[Uploading and downloading via ftp with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354012/uploading-and-downloading-via-ftp-with-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

I've made good use of [this FTP library](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon) in my own iOS app

Comment: I have download the example, but where it saves the downloaded files?

Comment: @DanM = It saves the downloaded file where ever you choose to save it. Look at the README.md.