# Xcode - How to upload a Text File (.txt) to a FTP Server

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file-upload, ftp, text-files

How to create a TextFile(.txt.) in my iPhone App and then upload it to my FTP server.(from iPhone)?

i think i have to put my Password/UserName to my FTP Server in the code, is that safe?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of libaries which you can use like :

- https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit

You can also use this example by apple.

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Notice that github is currently down for maintenance.

source: [iPhone FTP Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281109/iphone-ftp-integration)