# Xcode iPhone SDK - Uploading a file

Tags: ios, file-upload

I want to upload a file to a website (In this case [MediaFire](http://mediafire.com/))

Non-working code i got so far:

```
NSString *File2upload = @"Documents/data.xml";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://username@hotmail.com:password@mediafire.com/data.xml"];
[File2upload writeToURL:url atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than ignore the error (by passing `NULL` as the `error:` argument), you should take a look at the `NSError` object returned by the call. The name of the `NSString` method you're calling (`writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:`) may suggest you can use arbitrary schemes, but in fact only `file://...` urls will work.

If you want to upload a file to an ftp server, you'll need to use an ftp client library, such as those mentioned in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434552/best-ftp-objective-c-wrapper-for-iphone).