# Ftp client library for iphone in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ftp

Hi im new to iphone development im currently try to develop an application in which i want to perform ftp operation such as file upload,download, list files for which i want good ftp client class library in objective c, i found some paid library which i cant affort.can any one suggest me good ftp client library for iphone in objective c.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434552/best-ftp-objective-c-wrapper-for-iphone

Answer (score 2):

s7ftprequest only for uploading files to FTP.

The below is sample code from apple

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Limitations:

```
FTPS (that is, FTP over TLS)
deleting items
renaming items
other less common FTP commands
custom FTP commands
```

Comment: S7FTPRequest is now called SCRFTPRequest and located here https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest

Comment: below code is deprecated for ios 9+
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

You can this library for downloading and uploading files from ftp server.

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp

Answer (score 0):

Wrote an easy to use ftp uploader for iOS and it runs on a background thread courtesy of ASIHTTPReq. However, it can only do basic uploading for now. But i guarantee you it's really easy to use

https://github.com/soulslicer/QueueFTP