# Change name of file on ftp server IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ftp

just have a simple question is there a way I can change name of file on FTP server, using standard iOS SDK, or any other library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [CFNetwork FTP docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH9-SW1) don't mention your case specifically, but there may be a way to sent RNFR and RNTO commands over the stream. Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2434552/1224741) may be of use to you. Either way, I think you have your work cut out for you.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try HTTP protocol, send the rename command by http;

that means your FTP server should support FTP&HTTP.